# Wordpress Widget jquery live() or on(), admin side

Tags: wordpress, widget

something disturbing me since a while, jQuery API says :

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.
```

As I try to add some jquery stuff in my widget admin side ( *form() action of widget class* ), I was surprise to not be able to use on(), but live() to do the job.

So here is my question : **Why and what am I misunderstanding ?**

Regards, and of course, thx for your time.

ps I'm offcurse using >= 1.7 version.

Edit:

```
<?php
    class Test_Slider_Widget extends WP_Widget 
        { 
            public function form( $instance ) { 
                ?>
             <span id="test">Test</span>
             <script> 
             jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                 /* $('#test').on('click', function { //doesn't work
                     alert('test'); 
                 }); */
                 $('#test').live('click', function { //work
                     alert('test');
                 });

             });
             </script>


 <?php }
```

EDIT 2: Ok, always use $this->get_field_id('id-text') to have a unique ID, or id will be duplicated cause of widget duplicated code in wordpress admin.
Thanks to **Xec** for showing me the way :)

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated `.live()` method binds to `document`, and on each and every click will check to see if the `#test` selector matches before invoking the handler. If you want this behavior with `.on()` you can use the *delegate syntax*.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events for more detailed information.

For a quick-fix you can mimic your `.live()` code with something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

For more efficient code you would replace `document` with a selector matching a static ancestor of `#test`

Hope this helps!

**edit:**

From your "edit 2" I realize your issue was duplicated IDs, but i'll leave this answer here for posterity.